# How to call controller function from directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm using Angularjs and I want to call controller function from directives but it is not working please help.

Below my code

```
app.directive('datetimez', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
            }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
                changedate();
                //ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
                //scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Controller :

```
app.controller('GetIncidentcnt', function ($scope) {

    $scope.changedate = function () {
        alert('Hi#####fromdate');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
    <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" data-date-start-date="+0d" name="input1"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to call `changedate()` from directive function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can have a case where you need to use it multiple times on your page, In that case calling controller method from directive will get messed up, when you wanted to call different method on each `datepicker`.

So I'd suggest you to use isolated `scope` there to make a reusable component.
For that you need to add `scope: { onChange: '&' },`, that will make available to directive using `&` (which indicates expression to executed)by adding `on-change` attribute on your directive element that will provide the controller method contract.

**Markup**

```
<div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1" on-change="changedate()">
```

**Directive**

```
   app.directive('datetimez', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
               onChange: '&'
            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                element.datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
                }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
                    //to run digest cycle to..
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                       scope.onChange();
                    })

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: You still have `on-click` in the markup example; it should be `on-change`.

Comment: @JackA. thanks mate..I was forget that attribute to change

Answer (score 1):

Providing the directive is declared within the controller's scope (in a template) you simply need to reference the method on the directive's inherited `scope` object, given as an argument to the `link` method:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    element.datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        scope.changedate();
//      ^^^^^
    });
}
```

Comment: after calling controller method..you need to run digest cycle manually to see the effects..